# ogr2ogr issues in clipping tab to shp where tab has points and lines together

Tags: ogr, ogr2ogr, osgeo4w

I am running a simple script to clip and convert all tab files in a directory via osgeo shell

```
for %f in (*.TAB) do ogr2ogr "%~dpnf_Clip.shp" -clipsrc "clipped\AOI.TAB" "%f" -f "ESRI Shapefile"
```

It mostly works but for some files I get

> ERROR 1: Attempt to write non-point (LINESTRING) geometry to point
>   shapefile. 
>   ERROR 1: Unable to write feature 602 from layer
>   Water_Notes_DSC.
>   ERROR 1: Terminating translation prematurely after
>   failed

How can I get it to split these features into _point, _line and _poly automatically?

Comment: there's a little option in the help that isn't explained http://www.gdal.org/ogr2ogr.html [layer[layer..]] it seems that you can specify Point, Line (polyline) or Polygon layer from your TAB, which supports multiple geometry types in the same file, into a shapefile which supports only one geometry type.

Comment: There is only one layer in that tab so that won't work.

Comment: If you use orginfo your_tab_file, you may get more info, the features are grouped by geometry type and have an ordinal number (org calls it layer).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MapInfo tab can contain several layers but obviously in this case there is just one layer that holds several kind of geometries. Like this one that I made for testing:

```
ogrinfo mixed.tab mixed
INFO: Open of `mixed.tab'
      using driver `MapInfo File' successful.

Layer name: mixed
Geometry: Unknown (any)
Feature Count: 3
OGRFeature(mixed):1
  FID (Integer) = 1
  POINT (260000.01 7240000.01)

OGRFeature(mixed):2
  FID (Integer) = 2
  LINESTRING (159999.99 7039999.99,300000 7140000,189999.99 7210000.01)

OGRFeature(mixed):3
  FID (Integer) = 3
  POLYGON ((-30000.0 7240000.01,39999.99 7159999.99,99999.99 7279999.99,-30000.0 7240000.01))
```

I suggest to use ogr2ogr with the -sql parameter. As documented in http://www.gdal.org/ogr_sql.html you can select features by the geometry type.

```
ogr2ogr -f "ESRI Shapefile" points.shp mixed.tab -sql "SELECT* FROM mixed where ogr_geometry='POINT' OR ogr_geometry='MULTIPOINT'"

ogr2ogr -f "ESRI Shapefile" lines.shp mixed.tab -sql "SELECT* FROM mixed where ogr_geometry='LINESTRING' OR ogr_geometry='MULTILINESTRING'"

ogr2ogr -f "ESRI Shapefile" polygons.shp mixed.tab -sql "SELECT* FROM mixed where ogr_geometry='POLYGON' OR ogr_geometry='MULTIPOLYGON'"
```

Comment: this, or use the `-where "<filter_expression"` flag or the `-nlt <geometry_type>` flag

Comment: Layer type (-nlt) may give unexpected result. It converts polygon also to line layer as a linear ring.

Comment: @user30184 great suggestion but the problem is that it's being run on a whole directory of files where I don't know if the tab being processed has more than one kind of geometry. Apart from creating a python process that does an ogrinfo and if there's more than one type, it uses your code example with -sql to split an input file into outfile_line, outfile_poly, outfile_point -can you think of a way to do this within a simple one-liner?

Comment: Brute force is to run all three commands. It is not necessarily so slow.